# blocking sdk wrapper function in a DM scripting thread

Tags: sdk, dm-script

I have written a dll with the DM3 SDK containing a blocking function ( boost::asio::read(...) ). I aim to use the incoming data in another thread in real time.
However to my understanding, if this SDK function is executed as a thread within the DM scripting language side, it should not freeze the DM software or not even block the DM scripting flow when the thread is started. However this is the case. How would I execute the function as a thread independently and not blocking?

Here is a simple example:

```
// $BACKGROUND$

number framenumber = 0

class testthread  : thread
{

testthread( Object self) Result("\n testthread (ID:"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()+") created.")
~testthread( Object self) Result("\n testthread (ID:"+self.ScriptObjectGetID()+") destroyed.")

    void RunThread(object self)
    {   
    SU_HostAcquisition(framenumber)
    }
}   

Class Dialog_UI : UIFrame
    {

    object acquisitionobj

    void startpressed(object self) 
        {
        self.startthread("CountingThread")
        }

    void CountingThread( object self)
        {
            Try 
            {

            // some code here for stuff
            acquisitionobj.StartThread()
            // some other code here for other stuff
            }
            Catch
            {
            result("canceled...  \n")
            }
        }


    TagGroup CreateDialog_UI( object self )
        {
            TagGroup Dialog_UI = DLGCreateDialog("test")
            taggroup startbutton=dlgcreatepushbutton("Start","startpressed").dlgidentifier("startbutton")
            Dialog_UI.dlgaddelement(startbutton)
            return Dialog_UI
        }

    object init(object self, object threadIn)
        {   
            acquisitionobj = threadIn   
            return self.super.init(self.CreateDialog_UI())
        }

        Dialog_UI( object self )
            {
                self.super.init( self.CreateDialog_UI() )
                number dialogID=self.ScriptObjectGetID()
                result("\nDialog created with ID:"+dialogID)
            }

        ~Dialog_UI( object self )
            {
                number dialogID=self.ScriptObjectGetID()
                result("\nDialog with ID: "+dialogID+" destroyed.")
            }

    }

void main()
    {
        // Create the dialog
        object obj = alloc(testthread)
        object Dialog_UI = Alloc(Dialog_UI).init(obj)
        Dialog_UI.Display("test")
        Return
    }


main()
```

The SU_HostAcquisition(framenumber) is the function from the created dll. So this code does not work without the dll, but any blocking function would do i guess....

Another option for me, would be to start the thread in the SDK side as boost::thread object. However I want to pass the function argument as a reference (or a pointer), so I can observe how it changes in real time in the DM scripting side. This works in a normal SDK function by passing the argument as "*argument". But it seems impossible when dealing with threads.... For example the following will not work, in the DM scripting side, it will update the command value by 1 in the hostthread(), but not in hosttask....

```
unsigned long hosttask(uint32 &command1)
{
command++;
return 0;
}

void SU_HostThread(uint32 *command)
{
command++;
boost::thread Hostthread = boost::thread(boost::bind(boost::move(hosttask), boost::ref(*command) ));
return;
}
```

any ideas?

thanks!

EDITED::::

I realized that I have to solve the second part of my problem with the SDK thread, since the whole camera acquisition process has to be defined within one thread only. Hence the problem is really how to make sure that the pointer argument "command" to be assigned as argument to the SU_HostThread() in the DM scripting interface, is actually pointing to the same address as the argument "command1", assigned to the thread object hosttask(). Boost::thread copies the argument by value, making sure that the argument exists for the whole life time of the thread, hence assigning new address to it. Usually, this can be overwritten by assigning the argument as boost::ref(command). But this does not work apparently within the DM software. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure I undestand all correctly, but your script above works (not blocking anything) if you replace your DLL call by any other call, say 'beep()', correct? So the question is, what is your SU_HostAcquisition() method actually doing? Be aware, that there are certain elements which will always end up on the main-thread (of DM), such as UI-related things in possibly some camera/hardware related things. Do you also see the problem, if your  SU_HostAcquisition() is just having the block and just a debug-output ?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, I can't help you with the edited question.

Comment: Minor comment: You don't need the // $BACKGROUND$ in your script above.